# Welcome Mail send with wrong store_id

Tags: magento-1.9, email, multistore, transactional-mail

I have a problem with **sending the Welcome Mail** after **confirmation**.
It is the translated standard welcome mail we have created in transactional emails (backend) and then configured on store view scope.

It´s always send in german (`store_id=1`) which is our default storeview.
I have already debugged it and ran into `code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php` l.351 where the welcome mail gets send and the `getSendemailStoreId()` seems to be the code where it always returns `store_id=1`, as it seems to be `null` first and then loading the default/first element of the store-id array that gets loaded somehow.

I tried to get the correct `store_id` based on customer, but it seems that `getStore()` and `getData()` on customer-object are not containing the correct ID and the only place where I could find the correct one was in `$customer-> _data['store_id']` (not in "data" !), but i could not get it out there !

I hope someone can help me to fix this strange behaviour.
Thank you !

[image: this is where you can send the mail via backend after customer has registered ->within manage customers]

[image: this is the snippet from customer controller]

Comment: will you please check store_id in store table in database. will see column store_id and website_id.

Comment: @bharatdesai i checked the table, and the store id´s are different starting with "1" for german, "26" for english and so on.website id´s always "1" as we only have one website...

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code in line 351 he is getting the `websiteId` and not a `storeID`, this config is available in : `Admin->Customer->Manage Customer->Account Information->Associate to Website`. if you want to get current Store id of a customer, you can use some code like this:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customerInfo = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId())->getData();
    Zend_Debug::dump($customerInfo);
}
```

Result:

```
[entity_id] => 1
[entity_type_id] => 1
[website_id] => 1
[group_id] => 1
[store_id] => 1
...
```

Comment: i tried to load customerinfo instead of l.352 (getSendemailStoreId()), but it did not work. The store_id was still not set correctly and this time it not even send any mail. I also don´t know if it is needed to check if customer is logged in, as they can´t be logged in until admin registered them and send the welcome mail (which is not being sent / sent in wrong language -> always german/ store_id="1")